# Elasticsearch - How to provide custom synonyms when querying?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm developping a search engine for my client which has to use synonym expansion. I can properly setup my index with a synonym token filter and a custom file (synonym.txt).

Example: ipod, i-pod, i pod

However, whenever we want a synonym expansion, I get the synonyms from Elasticsearch and display them as tags on the website.
Each tag can be unselected. In this case, how can we specify while querying to Elasticsearch, to use a different set of synonyms, not coming from the synonym.txt file ?

Example: if the user is looking for the term ipod, then I will show these two tags: i-pod, i pod. But if the user chooses to unselect "i-pod", I would like to be able to specify that only "i pod" is a synonym of "ipod" while querying.

My index settings are :

```
{
                "settings": {
                    "analysis": {
                      "filter": {
                        "elision": {
                          "type": "elision",
                          "articles": ["l", "m", "t", "qu", "n", "s", "j", "d", "c", "jusqu", "quoiqu", "lorsqu", "puisqu"]
                        },
                        "french_stop": {
                            "type":    "stop",
                            "stopwords":  "_french_"
                        },
                        "french_stemmer": {
                            "type": "stemmer",
                            "language": "light_french"
                        },
                        "synonymsFilter": {
                            "type" : "synonym",
                            "synonyms_path" : "analysis/synonym.txt"
                        },
                          "autocompleteFilter": {
                            "max_shingle_size": "5",
                            "min_shingle_size": "2",
                            "type": "shingle"
                          }
                      },
                      "analyzer": {
                        "default": {
                          "tokenizer": "letter",
                          "filter": ["asciifolding", "lowercase", "french_stemmer", "elision", "french_stop"]
                        },
                          "auto-complete-suggester": {
                            "filter": [
                              "lowercase",
                              "autocompleteFilter"
                            ],
                            "char_filter": [
                              "html_strip"
                            ],
                            "type": "custom",
                            "tokenizer": "standard"
                          },
                        "did-you-mean-suggester": {
                            "tokenizer": "standard",
                            "filter": ["asciifolding", "lowercase"]
                        },
                        "synonym_analyzer" : {
                            "tokenizer" : "whitespace",
                            "filter" : ["synonymsFilter"]
                        },
                        "synonym_analyzer2": {
                            "tokenizer": "standard",
                            "filter": ["asciifolding", "lowercase", "french_stop", "autocompleteFilter"]
                        }
                      }
                    }
                },
                "mappings": {
                                            "companies": {
                                                "date_detection": "false",
                                                "properties": {
                                                    "auto_complete": {
                                                        "type": "string",
                                                        "analyzer": "auto-complete-suggester",
                                                        "term_vector" : "yes"
                                                    },
                                                      "did_you_mean": {
                                                        "type": "string",
                                                        "analyzer": "did-you-mean-suggester",
                                                        "term_vector" : "yes"
                                                      },
                                                      "synonyms": {
                                                        "type": "string",
                                                        "analyzer": "synonym_analyzer",
                                                        "term_vector" : "yes"
                                                      },
                                                    "company_name": {
                                                        "type": "string",
                                                         "fields": {
                                                            "raw":   { "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed" },
                                                             "suggester":   { "type": "string", "analyzer": "did-you-mean-suggester" }
                                                         },
                                                         "term_vector" : "yes",
                                                        "copy_to": [
                                                          "did_you_mean",
                                                          "auto_complete",
                                                          "synonyms"
                                                        ]
                                                    },
                                                    "siren": {
                                                        "type": "string",
                                                         "fields": {
                                                             "raw":   { "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed" },
                                                             "suggester":   { "type": "string", "analyzer": "did-you-mean-suggester" }
                                                         }
                                                    },
                                                    "CPposteEntreprise": {
                                                        "type": "string",
                                                        "fields": {
                                                            "raw":   { "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed" },
                                                            "suggester":   { "type": "string", "analyzer": "did-you-mean-suggester" }
                                                        }
                                                    },
                                                    "commercial_company_name": {
                                                        "type": "string",
                                                         "fields": {
                                                            "raw":   { "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed" },
                                                             "suggester":   { "type": "string", "analyzer": "did-you-mean-suggester" }
                                                         },
                                                         "term_vector" : "yes",
                                                            "copy_to": [
                                                              "did_you_mean",
                                                              "auto_complete",
                                                              "synonyms"
                                                            ]
                                                    },
                                                    "year_creation_company": {
                                                        "type": "long"
                                                    },
                                                    "month_creation_company": {
                                                        "type": "long"
                                                    },
                                                    "month_year_creation_company": {
                                                        "type": "date",
                                                        "format": "yyyyMM",
                                                         "fields": {
                                                             "raw":   { "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed" }
                                                         }
                                                    },
                                                    "city_company": {
                                                        "type": "string",
                                                         "fields": {
                                                             "suggester":   { "type": "string", "analyzer": "did-you-mean-suggester" }
                                                         },
                                                         "term_vector" : "yes",
                                                            "copy_to": [
                                                              "did_you_mean",
                                                              "auto_complete"
                                                            ]
                                                    },
                                                    "departement_company": {
                                                        "type": "string",
                                                        "fields": {
                                                            "raw":   { "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed" },
                                                            "suggester":   { "type": "string", "analyzer": "did-you-mean-suggester" }
                                                        },
                                                        "term_vector" : "yes",
                                                           "copy_to": [
                                                             "did_you_mean",
                                                             "auto_complete"
                                                           ]
                                                    },
                                                    "region_company": {
                                                        "type": "string",
                                                        "fields": {
                                                            "raw":   { "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed" },
                                                            "suggester":   { "type": "string", "analyzer": "did-you-mean-suggester" }
                                                        },
                                                        "term_vector" : "yes",
                                                           "copy_to": [
                                                             "did_you_mean",
                                                             "auto_complete"
                                                           ]
                                                    },
                                                    "is_excellence": {
                                                        "type": "string",
                                                        "fields": {
                                                            "raw":   { "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed" },
                                                            "suggester":   { "type": "string", "analyzer": "did-you-mean-suggester" }
                                                        }
                                                    },
                                                    "interlocuteurs": {
                                                        "type": "string",
                                                         "fields": {
                                                            "raw":   { "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed" },
                                                             "suggester":   { "type": "string", "analyzer": "did-you-mean-suggester" }
                                                         },
                                                         "term_vector" : "yes",
                                                            "copy_to": [
                                                              "did_you_mean",
                                                              "auto_complete"
                                                            ]
                                                    },
                                                    "flag_entreprise_finance": {
                                                        "type": "string",
                                                        "fields": {
                                                            "raw":   { "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed" }
                                                        }
                                                    },
                                                    "flag_indirect": {
                                                        "type": "string",
                                                        "fields": {
                                                            "raw":   { "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed" }
                                                        }
                                                    },
                                                    "flag_direct": {
                                                        "type": "string",
                                                        "fields": {
                                                            "raw":   { "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed" }
                                                        }
                                                    },
                                                    "flag_investissement": {
                                                        "type": "string",
                                                        "fields": {
                                                            "raw":   { "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed" }
                                                        }
                                                    },
                                                    "montant_total_investissement": {
                                                        "type": "double",
                                                        "fields": {
                                                            "raw":   { "type": "double", "index": "not_analyzed" }
                                                        }
                                                    },
                                                    "motant_total_finance": {
                                                        "type": "double",
                                                        "fields": {
                                                            "raw":   { "type": "double", "index": "not_analyzed" }
                                                        }
                                                    },
                                                    "nombre_investissement": {
                                                        "type": "long",
                                                        "fields": {
                                                            "raw":   { "type": "long", "index": "not_analyzed" }
                                                        }
                                                    },
                                                    "nombre_financement_accorde": {
                                                        "type": "long",
                                                        "fields": {
                                                            "raw":   { "type": "long", "index": "not_analyzed" }
                                                        }
                                                    },
                                                    "caInterne": {
                                                        "type": "double",
                                                        "fields": {
                                                            "raw":   { "type": "double", "index": "not_analyzed" }
                                                        }
                                                    },
                                                    "caExterne": {
                                                        "type": "double",
                                                        "fields": {
                                                            "raw":   { "type": "double", "index": "not_analyzed" }
                                                        }
                                                    },
                                                    "caFiltre": {
                                                        "type": "double",
                                                        "fields": {
                                                            "raw":   { "type": "double", "index": "not_analyzed" }
                                                        }
                                                    },
                                                    "effectif": {
                                                        "type": "double",
                                                        "fields": {
                                                            "raw":   { "type": "double", "index": "not_analyzed" }
                                                        }
                                                    },
                                                    "textRank": {
                                                        "type": "string",
                                                        "fields": {
                                                            "raw":   { "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed" }
                                                        },
                                                        "term_vector" : "yes",
                                                         "copy_to": [
                                                            "synonyms"
                                                         ]
                                                    },
                                                    "masterKeywords": {
                                                        "type": "nested",
                                                        "properties": {
                                                            "keyword": {
                                                                "type":"string",
                                                                "fields": {
                                                                    "raw":   { "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed" }
                                                                },
                                                                "term_vector" : "yes",
                                                                "copy_to": [
                                                                    "did_you_mean",
                                                                    "auto_complete"
                                                                ]
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    },
                                                    "dossiers":{
                                                        "type": "nested",
                                                         "date_detection": "false",
                                                         "properties": {
                                                             "dossierCommercial": {
                                                                 "type": "long"
                                                             },
                                                             "sousDossierCommercial": {
                                                                 "type": "long"
                                                             },
                                                             "historiqueProduitBPI": {
                                                                 "type": "string"
                                                             },
                                                             "statutSousDossier": {
                                                                 "type": "string"
                                                             },
                                                             "dateDecision": {
                                                                 "type": "date",
                                                                  "fields": {
                                                                      "suggester":   { "type": "string", "analyzer": "did-you-mean-suggester" },
                                                                      "raw":   { "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed" }
                                                                  }
                                                             },
                                                             "nomChargesAffaires": {
                                                                 "type": "string",
                                                                  "fields": {
                                                                      "suggester":   { "type": "string", "analyzer": "did-you-mean-suggester" }
                                                                  }
                                                             },
                                                             "contactChargesAffaires": {
                                                                 "type": "string",
                                                                  "fields": {
                                                                      "suggester":   { "type": "string", "analyzer": "did-you-mean-suggester" }
                                                                  }
                                                             },
                                                             "montantAide": {
                                                                 "type": "double",
                                                                  "fields": {
                                                                      "suggester":   { "type": "string", "analyzer": "did-you-mean-suggester" },
                                                                      "raw":   { "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed" }
                                                                  }
                                                             },
                                                             "contentValidation": {
                                                                 "type": "string",
                                                                  "fields": {
                                                                      "suggester":   { "type": "string", "analyzer": "did-you-mean-suggester" }
                                                                  },
                                                                  "term_vector" : "yes",
                                                                    "copy_to": [
                                                                      "did_you_mean",
                                                                      "auto_complete",
                                                                      "synonyms"
                                                                    ]
                                                             },
                                                             "contentDecision": {
                                                                 "type": "string",
                                                                  "fields": {
                                                                      "suggester":   { "type": "string", "analyzer": "did-you-mean-suggester" }
                                                                  },
                                                                  "term_vector" : "yes",
                                                                    "copy_to": [
                                                                      "did_you_mean",
                                                                      "auto_complete",
                                                                      "synonyms"
                                                                    ]
                                                             },
                                                             "contentDirectionEngagements": {
                                                                 "type": "string",
                                                                  "fields": {
                                                                      "suggester":   { "type": "string", "analyzer": "did-you-mean-suggester" }
                                                                  },
                                                                  "term_vector" : "yes",
                                                                    "copy_to": [
                                                                      "did_you_mean",
                                                                      "auto_complete",
                                                                      "synonyms"
                                                                    ]
                                                             },
                                                             "metaDomain": {
                                                                 "type": "string",
                                                                  "fields": {
                                                                      "suggester":   { "type": "string", "analyzer": "did-you-mean-suggester" }
                                                                  }
                                                             },
                                                             "sousSecteur": {
                                                                 "type": "string",
                                                                  "fields": {
                                                                      "suggester":   { "type": "string", "analyzer": "did-you-mean-suggester" }
                                                                  }
                                                             },
                                                             "keywords": {
                                                                 "type": "string",
                                                                  "fields": {
                                                                      "suggester":   { "type": "string", "analyzer": "did-you-mean-suggester" }
                                                                  },
                                                                  "term_vector" : "yes",
                                                                    "copy_to": [
                                                                      "did_you_mean",
                                                                      "auto_complete"
                                                                    ]
                                                             },
                                                             "descriptionProjet": {
                                                                 "type": "string",
                                                                  "fields": {
                                                                      "suggester":   { "type": "string", "analyzer": "did-you-mean-suggester" }
                                                                  },
                                                                  "term_vector" : "yes",
                                                                    "copy_to": [
                                                                      "did_you_mean",
                                                                      "auto_complete",
                                                                      "synonyms"
                                                                    ]
                                                             }
                                                         }
                                                    },
                                                    "investissements": {
                                                        "type": "nested",
                                                         "date_detection": "false",
                                                         "properties": {
                                                            "flag_indirect": {
                                                                "type": "string",
                                                                "fields": {
                                                                    "raw":   { "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed" }
                                                                }
                                                            },
                                                            "nom_societe_gestion_svi":{
                                                                "type": "string"
                                                            },
                                                            "date_entree_investissement":{
                                                                "type": "date",
                                                                 "fields": {
                                                                     "raw":   { "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed" }
                                                                 }
                                                            },
                                                            "montant_investissement_df":{
                                                                "type": "double"
                                                            },
                                                            "description_projet_investissement":{
                                                                "type": "string",
                                                                "term_vector" : "yes",
                                                                "copy_to": [
                                                                  "did_you_mean",
                                                                  "auto_complete",
                                                                  "synonyms"
                                                                ]
                                                            }
                                                         }
                                                    },
                                                    "bilans":{
                                                        "type": "nested",
                                                         "date_detection": "false",
                                                         "properties": {
                                                             "bilanAnneeN": {
                                                                 "properties": {
                                                                     "effectif": {
                                                                         "type": "long",
                                                                         "fields": {
                                                                             "raw":   { "type": "long", "index": "not_analyzed" }
                                                                         }
                                                                     },
                                                                     "capital": {
                                                                         "type": "double"
                                                                     },
                                                                     "resultatNet": {
                                                                         "type": "double"
                                                                     },
                                                                     "clotureDate": {
                                                                         "type": "date"
                                                                     },
                                                                     "annee": {
                                                                         "type": "long"
                                                                     },
                                                                     "ebeMoyen": {
                                                                         "type": "double"
                                                                     },
                                                                    "caInterne": {
                                                                        "type": "double",
                                                                        "fields": {
                                                                            "raw":   { "type": "double", "index": "not_analyzed" }
                                                                        }
                                                                    },
                                                                    "caExterne": {
                                                                        "type": "double",
                                                                        "fields": {
                                                                            "raw":   { "type": "double", "index": "not_analyzed" }
                                                                        }
                                                                    }
                                                                 }
                                                             },
                                                             "bilanAnneeN1": {
                                                                 "properties": {
                                                                     "effectif": {
                                                                         "type": "long",
                                                                         "fields": {
                                                                             "raw":   { "type": "long", "index": "not_analyzed" }
                                                                         }
                                                                     },
                                                                     "capital": {
                                                                         "type": "double"
                                                                     },
                                                                     "resultatNet": {
                                                                         "type": "double"
                                                                     },
                                                                     "clotureDate": {
                                                                         "type": "date"
                                                                     },
                                                                     "annee": {
                                                                         "type": "long"
                                                                     },
                                                                     "ebeMoyen": {
                                                                         "type": "double"
                                                                     },
                                                                    "caInterne": {
                                                                        "type": "double",
                                                                        "fields": {
                                                                            "raw":   { "type": "double", "index": "not_analyzed" }
                                                                        }
                                                                    },
                                                                    "caExterne": {
                                                                        "type": "double",
                                                                        "fields": {
                                                                            "raw":   { "type": "double", "index": "not_analyzed" }
                                                                        }
                                                                    }
                                                                 }
                                                             },
                                                             "bilanAnneeN2": {
                                                                 "properties": {
                                                                     "effectif": {
                                                                         "type": "long",
                                                                         "fields": {
                                                                             "raw":   { "type": "long", "index": "not_analyzed" }
                                                                         }
                                                                     },
                                                                     "capital": {
                                                                         "type": "double"
                                                                     },
                                                                     "resultatNet": {
                                                                         "type": "double"
                                                                     },
                                                                     "clotureDate": {
                                                                         "type": "date"
                                                                     },
                                                                     "annee": {
                                                                         "type": "long"
                                                                     },
                                                                     "ebeMoyen": {
                                                                         "type": "double"
                                                                     },
                                                                    "caInterne": {
                                                                        "type": "double",
                                                                        "fields": {
                                                                            "raw":   { "type": "double", "index": "not_analyzed" }
                                                                        }
                                                                    },
                                                                    "caExterne": {
                                                                        "type": "double",
                                                                        "fields": {
                                                                            "raw":   { "type": "double", "index": "not_analyzed" }
                                                                        }
                                                                    }
                                                                 }
                                                             }
                                                         }
                                                    },
                                                    "news": {
                                                        "type": "nested",
                                                        "date_detection": "false",
                                                        "properties": {
                                                            "date": {
                                                                "type": "date",
                                                                 "fields": {
                                                                     "suggester":   { "type": "string", "analyzer": "did-you-mean-suggester" },
                                                                     "raw":   { "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed" }
                                                                 }
                                                            },
                                                            "description": {
                                                                "type": "string",
                                                                "term_vector" : "yes",
                                                                "copy_to": [
                                                                  "did_you_mean",
                                                                  "auto_complete",
                                                                  "synonyms"
                                                                ]
                                                            },
                                                            "title": {
                                                                "type": "string"
                                                            },
                                                            "content": {
                                                                "type": "string",
                                                                "term_vector" : "yes",
                                                                "copy_to": [
                                                                  "did_you_mean",
                                                                  "auto_complete",
                                                                  "synonyms"
                                                                ]
                                                            },
                                                            "url": {
                                                                "type": "string"
                                                            },
                                                            "tags": {
                                                                "type": "string",
                                                                "term_vector" : "yes",
                                                                "copy_to": [
                                                                  "did_you_mean",
                                                                  "auto_complete"
                                                                ]
                                                            },
                                                            "links": {
                                                                "type": "string"
                                                            },
                                                            "external_source": {
                                                                "type": "string"
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                }
            }
```

For now, I am using a master field called "synonyms". Is this a good idea ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You can have another custom analyzer composed of another synonym token filter that you can use only at search time (i.e. using `search_analyzer`). If you show your current index settings and mappings, a sample query and what your exact expectations are, we can go forward.

Comment: My query is a simple match query over synonyms. To get the synonyms out of Elasticsearch, I am using the Analyzer API. What I would like to do is to remove some synonyms at query time. Do you need anything else ?

Comment: Any chance to get a properly formatted and complete JSON? Easier to reproduce your problem.